# Equivalent using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

For some work that I am doing recently, I need the following operation to be done.

```
def myfunc(a, b):
    return a*b  # some operation here

a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,4,6,8]
print [[myfunc(i, j) for i in a] for j in b]
```

I need to create a 2D array from 1D arrays as shown above.
Can someone please tell me a way to do this using `numpy` operations..?

The arrays `a` and `b` are really long. So I'm assuming numpy will increase the performance.

Comment: For performance, it would make sense to vectorize the func itself. So, what exactly is the `operation` in your actual use case?

Comment: @Divakar: It is `a * log(a/b)`

Comment: What result you want to get from arrays `a = [1,2,3]` and `b = [2,4,6,8]` ?

Comment: @Ramesh-X as specified by Jaroslaw, it is always a good idea to include a small example with the input and the output you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use numpy [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([2,4,6,8])
a = a[:, None]
b = b[None, :]

a * np.log(a/b)
```

adding a new axis to `a` and `b` (as second and first axis respectively) will make `a`'s shape `(3, 1)` and `b`'s shape `(1, 4)`. Then, `a/b` a 2D `(3, 4)` array where the `i`-th column is `a[i]/b`:

```
a/b
array([[ 0.5       ,  0.25      ,  0.16666667,  0.125     ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.5       ,  0.33333333,  0.25      ],
       [ 1.5       ,  0.75      ,  0.5       ,  0.375     ]])
```

Then you can take the pointwise log and multiply by `a`. Since `np.log(a/b)` is (3, 4) and `a` is (3, 1), `a` will again be broadcasted to (3, 4).

A small subtlety is that, due to the way broadcasting happens, adding the second axis to `b` is not mandatory. I prefer writing it out explicitly nevertheless, for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to your function

```
a * np.log(np.divide.outer(a, b)).T

[[-0.69314718  0.          1.21639532]
 [-1.38629436 -1.38629436 -0.86304622]
 [-1.79175947 -2.19722458 -2.07944154]
 [-2.07944154 -2.77258872 -2.94248776]]
```

---

compare to your solution

```
f = lambda a, b: a * np.log(a/b)

np.array([[f(i, j) for i in a] for j in b])

[[-0.69314718  0.          1.21639532]
 [-1.38629436 -1.38629436 -0.86304622]
 [-1.79175947 -2.19722458 -2.07944154]
 [-2.07944154 -2.77258872 -2.94248776]]
```